# 1280x800 video screen capture converting to 720x480 mp4

Tags: handbrake

When doing a PC full screen video capture with ZD Soft Screen Recorder with a 1280x800 PC display and then converting to 720x480 mp4, does it make a noticeable difference using HD or a lesser streaming rate for the initial capture?

Answer (score 0):

You will get better results if your capture is of a similar size to your final
resolution.

This is because the larger the difference between the resolution of the video
and the wanted resolution, the more work of interpolation is required.

That said, the difference between 1280x800 and 720x480 does not seem to me
large enough to cause a noticeable lose of quality.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to just leave the resolution as captured.  1280x800 into Handbrake, 1280x800 out.